# Numpy installation dependency

Tags: python, linux, numpy, scipy

I am trying to update my machine and have ran into a problem.  I followed instructions on this page: http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux .   It seems the newer Numpy/Scipy versions want an older version of Python.  I am currently running Python 2.6.6 on Scientific Linux Fermi 6.2 (64bit).

```
yum install python-numpy python-scipy
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, protectbase, refresh-packagekit, security
Repository science_ScientificLinux is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-numpy.x86_64 0:1.6.1-15.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python < 2.5 for package: python-numpy-1.6.1-15.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfortran.so.1()(64bit) for package: python-numpy-1.6.1-  15.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libblas.so.3()(64bit) for package: python-numpy-1.6.1-15.1.x86_64
---> Package python-scipy.x86_64 0:0.6.0-6.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python < 2.5 for package: python-scipy-0.6.0-6.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfftw3.so.3()(64bit) for package: python-scipy-0.6.0-6.3.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libgfortran-41.x86_64 0:4.1.2-39.el6 will be installed
---> Package fftw.x86_64 0:3.2.1-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libblas3.x86_64 0:3.3.1-10.1 will be installed
---> Package python-numpy.x86_64 0:1.6.1-15.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python < 2.5 for package: python-numpy-1.6.1-15.1.x86_64
---> Package python-scipy.x86_64 0:0.6.0-6.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python < 2.5 for package: python-scipy-0.6.0-6.3.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-numpy-1.6.1-15.1.x86_64 (science_ScientificLinux)
       Requires: python < 2.5
       Installed: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (@slf-security)
           python = 2.6.6-29.el6_2.2
       Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6.i686 (slf)
           python = 2.6.6-29.el6
Error: Package: python-scipy-0.6.0-6.3.x86_64 (science_ScientificLinux)
       Requires: python < 2.5
       Installed: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (@slf-security)
           python = 2.6.6-29.el6_2.2
       Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6.i686 (slf)
           python = 2.6.6-29.el6
```

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: No experience with yum but you could try installing the packages with `pip` instead